# Dynamically alter Streamlit.multiselectbox options

Tags: python, multi-select, streamlit

I have a multiselectbox in the sidebar of my streamlit app. Without loss of generality:

- I have 10 options to put in this multiselectbox (these are the numbers 1...10)
- The user may not select both `1` and `2` simultaneously

I would therefore like to remove `2` from the list of possible selections if `1` is selected, but streamlit seems to have no capability for this, so I tried to wrap it in a loop, which also fails (`DuplicateWidgetID: There are multiple identical st.multiselect widgets with the same generated key.`):

```
options = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

space = st.sidebar.empty()
answer, _answer = [], None
while True:
    if answer != _answer:
        answer.append(space.multiselectbox("Pick a number",
                                           options,
                                           default=answer
                                           )
                      )
        options = [o for o in options if o not in answer]
        if 1 in options:
            if 2 in options: options.remove(2)
        if 2 in options:
            if 1 in options: options.remove(1)
        _answer = answer[:]
```

Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

Comment: [This](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/disallow-certain-selection-combinations-in-st-multiselect/1614/3) seems to mean this is impossible to do with just StreamLit

Comment: On `The user may not select both 1 and 2 simultaneously` how do you communicate that to the user?

Comment: "how do you communicate that to the user?" By disabling option `2` when the user selects option `1`, so that `2` is no longer selectable. This would allow for more complex mutex logic

Comment: I have provided method 2 in my revised answer is that not enough?

Comment: Answer is updated, added method 3, to remove 2 or 1 if 1 or 2 is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

Here is one approach, provide a help on the widget, and just allow the user to select both 1 and 2 but then we have to filter out 2 if both are selected. Then you can just use the validated selection.

###### Code

```
import streamlit as st

ms = st.sidebar.multiselect('Pick a number',  list(range(1, 11)),
    help='Choose either 1 or 2 but not both. If both are selected 1 will be used.')

if 1 in ms and 2 in ms:
    ms.remove(2)

st.write('##### Valid Selection')
st.write(str(ms))
```

###### Output

Hover mouse on the `?` to show the help.

[image]

## Method 2

Use radio button for options 1 or 2 and the rest for multiselect.

###### Code

```
import streamlit as st

rb = st.sidebar.radio('Pick a number', [1, 2])

ms = st.sidebar.multiselect('Pick a number',  list(range(3, 11)))

selected = ms
selected.append(rb)

st.write('##### Valid Selection')
st.write(str(selected))
```

###### Output

[image]

## Method 3

When 1 is selected remove the 2 and then rerun to update the options. Likewise when 2 is selected remove the 1 and rerun to update the options.

###### Code

```
import streamlit as st


init_options = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


if 'options' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.options = init_options
if 'default' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.default = []


ms = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    label='Pick a number',
    options=st.session_state.options,
    default=st.session_state.default
)

# If 1 is selected, remove the 2 and rerun.
if 1 in ms:
    if 2 in st.session_state.options:
        st.session_state.options.remove(2)
        st.session_state.default = ms
        st.experimental_rerun()

# Else if 2 is selected, remove the 1 and rerun.
elif 2 in ms:
    if 1 in st.session_state.options:
        st.session_state.options.remove(1)
        st.session_state.default = ms
        st.experimental_rerun()


st.write('##### Valid Selection')
st.write(str(ms))
```

###### Output

[image]

Comment: While this is a really clear way to problem solve the UX (i.e. informing the user of the issue), it does not technically restrict the user from making bad selections. It is therefore not an answer to the question, even though it is helpful in other ways

Comment: Added 2nd method in the answer to address the issue.

Comment: Added method 3, to remove 2 or 1 if 1 or 2 is selected.